# insert multiple rows data into database fetched from another table

Tags: php, mysqli

i am trying to bulid an online attendace in php, i am fetching student list from student table, and want to put all chkboxs if checkd as present and if unchecked as absent,
i am unable to do that.

```
<div class="attendance">
    <form accept="att.php" method="POST">
            <?php 
            $sel_sql = "SELECT * FROM student";
            $run_sql = mysqli_query($conn,$sel_sql);
            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sql)){
                $id = $rows['id'];
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="'.$id.'" checked>'.ucfirst($rows['f_name']).'';
            }
        ?>


        <input type="submit" name="submit_attendance" value="Post Attendance">
        <?php echo $msg; ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

it shows prefect students list, but i dont know how to set insert query for all of these chkboxes

Comment: better give your table sample structure

Comment: What you actually want is still unclear. But for now first put that if attendance is marked as P then only show checked else don't show checked.

Comment: i want to put attandance to attandance table using list of student from student table. i can easily fetch users as checkboxes on page but i am unable to insert these students to attendance tble.

Answer (score 0):

try this query to insert from another table

```
SELECT * INTO TABLE2 FROM student
```

use `where` condition on student table as where student.column value to select checked values

Comment: u have whatsap? kindly send me, will send u detailed there? is that possible?

Comment: just update the table structure here in your question you can get multiple answers and choose the best one

Comment: have posted in from of pictures. kindly cehck it

Answer (score 0):

Applied same above things with checkbox input field

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="'.$id.'" 'if($row['present_field_of_database']) ? 'checked' : ''
'>'.ucfirst($rows['f_name']).'';
```

Comment: listen, i have two students in student table, i retreive them on a page as checkboxes.
now i want these checkbox to attandance table, i want insert query of multiple rows insert. on one click

Answer (score 0):

it's fine then updated code with your problems i hope it's work for you

```
    <div class="attendance">
        <form accept="att.php" method="POST">
                <?php 
                    $sel_sql = "SELECT * FROM student";
                    $run_sql = mysqli_query($conn,$sel_sql);


                    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sql)){
                        $id = $rows['id'];
                        // if your $id value is right from $rows['id'] then
                       // change your student table name to the another table where available status of the student
                        $wh_sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE id=".$id;
                        $run_wh_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $wh_sql);
                        $Wh_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_wh_sql);
                        // add student present or absent value to the rows data
                        $rows['status'] = $Wh_rows['status'];
                    }
                        // set value as A or P respectively absent or present add jquery plugins for onclick event while client click on checkbox change value respectively
                        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="'.$rows['status'].'" 'if($rows['status'] == "A") ?'checked': '' '>'.ucfirst($rows['f_name']).' onclick= "$(this).val(this.checked ? P : A)"';
                ?>

            <input type="submit" name="submit_attendance" value="Post Attendance">
            <?php echo $msg; ?>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: sir i dnt have any problem to retrieve, i want to post all students at once to database.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
        $s_id = $_POST['status'];
        $id = $_POST['student'];
        if ($s_id) {
            foreach ($s_id as $s) {
                foreach ($id as $i) {
                        if (mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO attendence(s_id,status) VALUES('".
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $s)."','".
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $i)."')")) {
                            $msg =  "success";
                        }else{
                            $msg =  "failed";
                        }
                    }   


            }
        }
    }
```

i have 3 students. when i press send it sends 9 entries. i am unable to understand how to insert all students data

Answer (score -1):

[This is attendance table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miVhA.png)

[This is attandance table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqjxX.png)

i want to put entries like this if check box chekd it wil post p and if not it wil post a. i just need how to insert all sutdent at once quert